# ActiveRecord: grouping with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 3 models: Location, UserReview, ContactDetail

Location has many user_reviews and has many contact_details

I want to select all Locations where the Location has 0 contact_details and order them in descending order by the last created user_review.

I can select all locations with 0 contact_details like this:

```
Location
  .includes(:contact_details)
  .where(contact_details: { location_id: nil } )
```

I can order all locations by last created user_review like this:

```
Location
  .left_joins(:user_reviews)
  .group('locations.id')
  .order('MAX(user_reviews.created_at) DESC')
```

I am having trouble combining these 2 queries. This throws an error:

```
Location
  .includes(:contact_details)
  .where(contact_details: { location_id: nil } )
  .left_joins(:user_reviews)
  .group('locations.id')
  .order('MAX(user_reviews.created_at) DESC')
```

Error:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "contact_details.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

What is the correct way to combine these queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includes` will try to create a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `contact_details` when there is a where clause, Use `join` instead:

```
 Location
  .left_outer_joins(:contact_details)
  .left_joins(:user_reviews)
  .group('locations.id')
  .having('COUNT(contact_details.id) = 0')
  .order('MAX(user_reviews.created_at) DESC')
```

Reference:

[Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

Comment: Ah makes perfect sense. Thanks!